# ADX Graph not clear

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have to calculate ADX for a given dataset and then plot it.The dataset consist of a 2-second candlestick of an instrument for a period of 5 days.i have verified the values of ADX from excel and it is coming out to be correct.But the plot I am getting is not according to the obtained values.
The code for final plot is

```
plt.plot(timestamp[29:len(closing_values)],ADX[29:len(closing_values)])
```

[image: obtained graph]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure the issue is with your dates. Make sure they are matlab serial dates or datetimes.

```
% function to convert matlab serial dates to yyymmdd format
serial2yyyymmdd = @(seryl) datevec(seryl)*[1e4 1e2 1 0 0 0]';

dta = randn(300,1);

figure;
subplot(2,1,1)
% plot with yyyymmdd dates
plot(serial2yyyymmdd(today-299:today),dta)
title('plot with yyyymmdd dates')
subplot(2,1,2)
% plot with matlab serial dates
plot(today-299:today,dta)
title('plot with matlab serial dates')
```

[image]

Comment: after doing what you suggested the plot now has some thick lines with spaces in between